# Object doesn't support property or method 'DataTable' - datatables not being applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

having a problem with datatables in my mvc 4 application.  my table (id=example) and data appear in my views, but datatables doesnt get applied, and i get the javascript runtime error:  Object doesn't support property or method 'DataTable'.

i've read several of the questions that may already have my answer, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322413/mvc-4-razor-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-datatable), but i just don't understand enough to fix this myself.  i'm pretty sure i've referenced jquery more than once in my _layout.cshtml page, but i dont know where.  it's below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")



        @*--CSS Files-- *@
        @*--Reset CSS-- *@
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css" />
        @*--jquery-ui css-- *@                  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        @*--DataTables CSS--*@              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" /> 
        @*--Custom Datatable CSS--  *@      <link href="../../Content/eventDataTable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        @*--jQuery Library--*@
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        @*--jquery-UI-- --*@
              <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        @*--DataTables-- *@
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        @*--DataTables ColumnFilters-- *@
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



        @if (false) {
            <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        }

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("MVC", "Index", "Home")</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </section>
                    @*<nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")    </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>*@
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
           @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; MVC Application @DateTime.Now.Year</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

       @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    </body>
</html>
```

below is the html and javascript from one of my views.  the table in the html above this javascript has an id of example

```
    @section featured {
@using (Html.BeginForm("Portland", "City", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CityForm" }))
{
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <center>
                @Html.DropDownList("OrderAsc", (SelectList)ViewData["CityName"], "-- Select Your City --",


         new    { 
             onchange = "dropDownList(this);"
                }   // end of new onchange

            ) @*End of Html.DropDownList*@

            </center>
        </div>
    </section>
    }
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<table id="example" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="display" >

<thead>

    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Day of Week</th>
        <th>Venue</th>
        <th>TicketLink</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Related</th>
    </tr>

    </thead>

    <tfoot>
     <tr>
        <th >Name</th>
        <th>Sort by date</th>
        <th>Weekday</th>
        <th> Venue</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Related</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>



 @foreach (MVC.Models.Event m in (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData.Model) {
    var ticketLinkText = m.TicketLink;  
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.Raw(m.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShowDate) Want to format dateTime*@
            @Html.Raw(m.ShowDate.Value.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Raw(m.DayOfWeek)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Raw(m.Venue)
        </td>
        <td>@if ( ticketLinkText.Contains("http"))
            {
        <a href ="@Html.Raw(m.TicketLink)" target="_blank">TicketLink</a>
            }
            else
            {
            @Html.Raw(m.TicketLink)
            }
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Raw(m.Status)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Raw(m.Related)
        </td>

    </tr>

}
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            //"bPaginate": true,
            //"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            //"bFilter": true,
            //"bSort": true,
            //"bInfo": false,
            //"bAutoWidth": true,
            //"aaSorting": [[1, "asc"]] //initial sorting once datatable is applied  


        })
          .columnFilter({ //sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
              aoColumns: [{ type: "text" },
                             { type: "date-range" },
                            { type: "text" },
                            { type: "text" },
                            null,
                            null,
                            { type: "text" },
                        ]

          });
    });

 </script>
```

also, here's my bundleconfig.cs since that was mentioned in several of the other posts i read.

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the table? is it coming in at @renderBody? maybe post it. If the table isn't formed  correctly, DataTable will throw an error

Comment: i edited and added the table.  thanks for the help.

Comment: you may have a conflict with your jquery files. A) see if it is loading twice. B) see if they are different versions

Comment: ok.  that's what i thought.  i'm unsure how to tell if it's loading twice or if there are different versions.  can you tell from above where it might be doing that?

Comment: see what version is in that scripts directory. check out 'sources` in the development tools on your browser.

Comment: I think @Cory is correct, it looks like jquery is loaded twice for a start. The way you're loading the javascript is a bit of a mess -  you've got a combination of bundles, file includes and inline code. This is certainly making it harder for you to debug.  Try to refactor the code to just use bundles.