# How to enable Bootstrap table pagination and search?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, pagination

I've been following [two](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/823490/Bootstrap-Table-With-Sorting-Searching-and-Paging) guides on adding pagination to a Bootstrap table, but when I add the required links and scripts, the pagination or search doesn't render on the bootstrap table.

I tried placing the jQuery reference at the start of the head tag as this solution suggested, but it made no difference.

I'm sure this is just a mismatch in the ordering of the external library cdn references but I'm not sure of the correct order.

I also checked that the script references the correct table, which it does - "escalation"

**Question:**

How can I organize `jquery` and `bootstrap` references to show table paging?

**Markup:** (gist of the view's markup)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <div class="page-header">
            <label class="heading">History</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <fieldset>
                    <form action="" class="form-group" method="post">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <div class="table-responsive">                            

                                <table id="escalation" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Application</th>
                                            <th>EMOPOP</th>
                                            <th>Stats</th>
                                            <th>Statement</th>
                                            <th>Time</th>
                                            <th>Updated</th>
                                            <th>Details</th>
                                            <th>Price</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                                            <td>System Architect</td>
                                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                            <td>61</td>
                                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                            <td>$320,800</td>
                                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                            <td>$320,800</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>            <!--END OF FORM ^^-->
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#escalation').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: should'nt be `$('#escalation').DataTable();` ?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I've tried .DataTable(); also which doesn't make a difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: In either case I get the error on IE, ` Object doesn't support property or method 'DataTable'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in case anyone else has a similar problem, the references were held in my layout page. This meant that the references in the view containing the table had no effect.

I updated the references in layout.cshtml to `jquery 1.9+` and also had to comment out the following which prevented the scripts from rendering:

```
//commented out
//@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
//@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

This was suggested in a similar question here:

[MVC 4 Razor Object doesn't support property or method 'dataTable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322413/mvc-4-razor-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-datatable)

Answer (score 7):

This code runs perfectly fine ,just test using the snipped below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html lang="en">   
<head>   
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<title>Final Output</title>   
<meta name="description" content="Bootstrap.">  
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>  
<body style="margin:20px auto">  
<div class="container">
<div class="row header" style="text-align:center;color:green">
<h3>Bootstrap</h3>
</div>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" >  
        <thead>  
          <tr>  
            <th>ENO</th>  
            <th>EMPName</th>  
            <th>Country</th>  
            <th>Salary</th>  
          </tr>  
        </thead>  
        <tbody>  
          <tr>  
            <td>001</td>  
            <td>Anusha</td>  
            <td>India</td>  
            <td>10000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>002</td>  
            <td>Charles</td>  
            <td>United Kingdom</td>  
            <td>28000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>003</td>  
            <td>Sravani</td>  
            <td>Australia</td>  
            <td>7000</td>  
          </tr>  
     <tr>  
            <td>004</td>  
            <td>Amar</td>  
            <td>India</td>  
            <td>18000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>005</td>  
            <td>Lakshmi</td>  
            <td>India</td>  
            <td>12000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>006</td>  
            <td>James</td>  
            <td>Canada</td>  
            <td>50000</td>  
          </tr>  
    
     <tr>  
            <td>007</td>  
            <td>Ronald</td>  
            <td>US</td>  
            <td>75000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>008</td>  
            <td>Mike</td>  
            <td>Belgium</td>  
            <td>100000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>009</td>  
            <td>Andrew</td>  
            <td>Argentina</td>  
            <td>45000</td>  
          </tr>  
    
      <tr>  
            <td>010</td>  
            <td>Stephen</td>  
            <td>Austria</td>  
            <td>30000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>011</td>  
            <td>Sara</td>  
            <td>China</td>  
            <td>750000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>012</td>  
            <td>JonRoot</td>  
            <td>Argentina</td>  
            <td>65000</td>  
          </tr>  
        </tbody>  
      </table>  
   </div>
</body>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

It's working here:

https://jsfiddle.net/bu4r2od4/

you need to use jQuery 1.9+

and use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#escalation').DataTable();
});
```

Comment: How can i dynamically add the rows to the table, in this example, we have static data for rows?

Comment: You can append using jquery `$('#escalation tbody').append('<tr>...</tr>');`